# TensorExpand can't expand in the presence of Hadamard product

Tags: linear-algebra, warning-messages, tensors

I'm trying to expand a symbolic matrix product. In the absence of Hadamard product everything works as expected:

```
P[t_] := P0 + E^(-t/3) P1;

Assuming[
 P0 ∈ Matrices[{4, 4}] && P1 ∈ Matrices[{4, 4}] && 
  v1 ∈ Vectors[4], TensorExpand[P[t0].P[t1].v1]]
```

> ```
> MatrixPower[P0, 2].v1 + E^(-(t0/3) - t1/3) MatrixPower[P1, 2].v1 + 
>  E^(-t1/3) P0.P1.v1 + E^(-t0/3) P1.P0.v1
> ```

But in the presence of a [Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)) `TensorExpand` can't expand:

```
Assuming[P0 ∈ Matrices[{4, 4}] && 
  P1 ∈ Matrices[{4, 4}] && v1 ∈ Vectors[4] && 
  v2 ∈ Vectors[4], 
 TensorExpand[P[t0].((P[t1].v1)*(P[t2].v2))]]
```

> TensorRank::ttimes: Product of nonscalar expressions encountered in
>   (P0+E^(-t2/3) P1).v2.
>
> TensorRank::ttimes: Product of nonscalar expressions encountered in
>   (P0+E^(-t1/3) P1).v2.
>
> TensorRank::ttimes: Product of nonscalar expressions encountered in
>   (P0+E^(-t2/3) P1).v2.
>
> General::stop: Further output of TensorRank::ttimes will be suppressed
>   during this calculation.
>
> ```
> P0.((P0.v1 + E^(-t1/3) P1.v1) (P0.v2 + E^(-t2/3) P1.v2)) + 
>  E^(-t0/3) P1.((P0.v1 + E^(-t1/3) P1.v1) (P0.v2 + E^(-t2/3) P1.v2))
> ```

Why this happens? How to avoid this problem?

Comment: Have you defined P[t0, 1] somewhere?

Comment: @bills It was a typo, I have corrected the question.

Answer (score 1):

As you noted, [`TensorExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorExpand) will not work if there are Hadamard products present. Instead, you can define your own function to do this, using [`Distribute`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Distribute) and defining a function to extract scalars:

```
myExpand[e_] := e /. h:Dot|Times -> Distribute @* h /. Dot -> scalarExtract @* Dot

scalarExtract[a_Dot] := Times @@ Flatten @ Reap[scalarExtract/@a]
scalarExtract[a_Times] := If[scalarQ[#], Sow[#];1, #]& /@ a
scalarExtract[a_] := a

scalarQ[a_] := TrueQ[TensorRank[a] == 0]
```

For your example:

```
P[t_] := P0 + E^(-t/3) P1

expr = P[t0].((P[t1].v1)*(P[t2].v2));

$Assumptions = (P0|P1) ∈ Matrices[{4,4}] && (v1|v2) ∈ Vectors[4] && (t0|t1|t2) ∈ Complexes;

myExpand[expr]
```

> P0.(P0.v1 P0.v2) + E^(-t1/3) P0.(P0.v2 P1.v1) + E^(-t2/3) P0.(P0.v1 P1.v2) + 
>    E^(-(t1/3) - t2/3) P0.(P1.v1 P1.v2) + E^(-t0/3) P1.(P0.v1 P0.v2) + 
>    E^(-(t0/3) - t1/3) P1.(P0.v2 P1.v1) + E^(-(t0/3) - t2/3) P1.(P0.v1 P1.v2) + 
>    E^(-(t0/3) - t1/3 - t2/3) P1.(P1.v1 P1.v2)

Let's check that the expressions are equivalent:

```
SeedRandom[0]
rules = {
    P0 -> RandomReal[1, {4,4}],
    P1 -> RandomReal[1, {4,4}],
    v1 -> RandomReal[1, 4],
    v2 -> RandomReal[1, 4],
    t0 -> RandomReal[1],
    t1 -> RandomReal[1],
    t2 -> RandomReal[1]
};

expr /. rules
myExpand[expr] /. rules
```

> {20.4585, 29.4332, 17.0382, 22.5295}
>
> {20.4585, 29.4332, 17.0382, 22.5295}

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `TensorRank` cannot find the the rank of the Hadamard product of two **symbolic** tensors.

```
$Assumptions = (v1 | v2) \[Element] Vectors[4]
TensorRank[v1 v2]
```

This flags an error.

> TensorRank::ttimes: Product of nonscalar expressions encountered in v1
>   v2.

However, if you are sure about the rank and dimension compatibilities, you can bypass this check by using `Inactivate` before `TensorExpand` and `Activate` it back after the action of `TensorExpand`:

```
Assuming[P0 \[Element] Matrices[{4, 4}] && 
   P1 \[Element] Matrices[{4, 4}] && v1 \[Element] Vectors[4] && 
   v2 \[Element] Vectors[4], 
  Inactivate@TensorExpand[P[t0].((P[t1].v1)*(P[t2].v2))]] // Activate
(*P0.((P0.v1 + E^(-t1/3) P1.v1) (P0.v2 + E^(-t2/3) P1.v2)) + E^(-t0/3) P1.((P0.v1 + E^(-t1/3) P1.v1) (P0.v2 + E^(-t2/3) P1.v2))*)
```

Comment: With your approach the output is the same as in the question: the matrix product isn't expanded.